# After installing ppa nvidia-390 graphics drivers, switching to intel graphics card results in nvidia drivers not being loaded at all. kubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intel

When switching prime profiles with the Nvidia x-server settings to internal intel graphics card, I am unable to switch back to the dedicated graphics card.
This is in part because the Nvidia driver does not load at all. The only error I get is the following while trying to start the nvidia x-settings;

```
~$ nvidia-settings
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

specs;
(NEOFETCH)

```
ccpeters@ccpeters-Lenovo-ideapad-510-15ISK 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: 80SR Lenovo ideapad 510-15ISK 
Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic 

Uptime: 17 mins 
Packages: 2465 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Icons: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX 
GPU: Intel Integrated Graphics 
Memory: 857MiB / 7882MiB
```

I'm using kde plasma 5.12 on kubuntu 18.04 LTS, with the nvidia-390 drivers.
I have overall noticed a lot of bugginess with nvidia under the new ubuntu 18.04 and have seen many bug reports of other people having problems as well.
This is probably completely nvidia's drivers fault.

Comment: You with AB Tiwary both have Lenovo Ideapads and many reasons may be behind Yours issues, laptop manufacturer and kernel/updated kernel not supporting it fully or new drivers from nVidia or their updated versions from ppa. Recently there was an update to 390.59 (form  390.48). May try 'ukuu' and install e.g kernel 4.16.12 or switch to nVidia 396.24. I'm not sure KDE/Kubuntu may cause some issues but under Ubuntu 17.10 I had also similar issue, could only use Intel and not login properly when switched to nVidia via prime-select.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The only way to switch back to the dedicated graphics card is to use nvidia-prime from terminal. Use this:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia 
reboot
```

Then you could use nvidia-settings again. The problem remains if you switch to the Intel graphics card, but I don't know a better way yet.
I found [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1765363).

So, there is no point to switch.